# How to find $E[\sqrt{X}]$ given only a distribution function?

Tags: probability

I'm given a continuous distribution function $F(x)$ and I should assume that $X$ is some random variable. My goal is to find the expected value of $\sqrt{X}$.

I'm very bad at probability but this is my attempt:

If I derivate the distribution function $F(x)$ I get the density function $f(x)$. Then $E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\cdot xdx$ 
But what about $\sqrt{X}$?

I'm asking this question in general terms so that I can calculate everything on my on. Though, any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\displaystyle E[\sqrt{X}] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\cdot \sqrt{x}dx$.

As Stefan Hansen comments, there is an issue if the is a non-zero probability of $X \lt 0$.

The [law of the unconscious statistician](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician)
 gives $\displaystyle E[g(X)] = \int f(x)g(x)dx$.

Comment: The square-root of a negative number?

Comment: @Stefan Hansen: as sensible as the expectation of a complex random variable

Comment: $F$ is continuous, not neccessarily absolutely continuous. It can be that no PDF exists.

Comment: Being casuistic is really unnecessary here, just change the bounds of the integral.

Answer (score 4):

If $U$ is a nonnegative random variable with CDF $H$ then:$$\mathbb{E}U=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(1-H\left(u\right)\right)du$$

Proof:

If function $g$ is prescribed by $\left(u,v\right)\mapsto1$ if $v>u$
and $\left(u,v\right)\mapsto0$ otherwise then:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(1-H\left(u\right)\right)du=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}g\left(u,v\right)dH\left(v\right)du=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}g\left(u,v\right)dudH\left(v\right)=\int_{0}^{\infty}vdH\left(v\right)=\mathbb{E}U$$

---

$\sqrt{X}$ only makes sense if we have $X\geq0$ so let us assume
that that is the case here.

If $F$ denotes the CDF of $X$ and $G$
the CDF of $\sqrt{X}$ then $G\left(x\right)=F\left(x^{2}\right)$.

$\sqrt{X}$ is a nonnegative rv and this implies that we can find $\mathbb{E}\sqrt{X}$ by means
of the mentioned rule: $$\mathbb{E}\sqrt{X}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(1-G\left(x\right)\right)dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(1-F\left(x^{2}\right)\right)dx$$

This allows you to find the expectation without differentiating $F$. You have in fact no guarantee that $F$ is differentiable. So this meets your needs. No PDF is involved. If a CDF is continuous then you are not allowed yet to conclude that it has a PDF. For that it must be 'absolutely continuous'.

Comment: Very nice result! Thank you so much.

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

We can use the [law of the unconscious statistician](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician)
 to find $\operatorname E\sqrt X$. We have that
$$
\operatorname E\sqrt X=\int_0^\infty\sqrt xf(x)\mathrm dx.
$$

Comment: $F$ is continuous, not neccessarily absolutely continuous. It can be that no PDF exists.

Comment: @drhab Thank you for the remark. Of course, my answer is valid only if there exists a pdf.